# Tx consuming script fails with: Caused by: (unConstrData #44000de140)... Third data argument, does not decode to a context when burning an NFT

Tags: plutus, cardano-serialization-lib, plutustx

I've this tx trying to submit to cardano-node `1.35.5`:

```
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
```

Where there are two scripts one for minting policy and the other for spending. I'm getting this error (sorry no enough characters for the error's text):

[image]

It basically says cannot call the spending script since cannot create the script context:
`The third data argument, does not decode to a context...`.

The scripts signature are like this:

```
userTokenValidate :: BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString -> Policy -> ValidatorHash -> Action -> ScriptContext -> Bool

referenceTokenValidate :: BuiltinByteString -> BuiltinByteString -> Policy -> DatumMetadata -> RefAction -> ScriptContext -> Bool
```

and this is the relevant data types:

```
data DatumMetadata = DatumMetadata {
                     metadata :: BuiltinData
                   , version :: Integer
                   , extra :: BuiltinData
}
instance Eq DatumMetadata where
    {-# INLINABLE (==) #-}
    (==) :: DatumMetadata -> DatumMetadata -> Bool
    DatumMetadata m v e == DatumMetadata m' v' e' = m == m' && v == v' && e == e'
makeLift ''DatumMetadata
makeIsDataIndexed ''DatumMetadata [('DatumMetadata, 0)]

data RefAction = Burn | Move | Upgrade
makeLift ''RefAction
makeIsDataIndexed ''RefAction [('Burn, 0), ('Move, 1), ('Upgrade, 2)]

data Action = MintNFT | BurnNFT | MintExtra
makeLift ''Action
makeIsDataIndexed ''Action [('MintNFT, 0), ('BurnNFT, 1), ('MintExtra, 2)]
```

Notice the first 3 parameters where parameterized for `referenceTokenValidate` and the 4 first for `userTokenValidate` so the final scripts passing to the tx are like "regular" scripts.

Here is the datum from the UTxO I want to spend it (it was created with data hash and real data in the witness set): https://preprod.cardanoscan.io/datumInspector?datum=d8799fa7446e616d655054616e676f434950303036382330313145696d6167655835697066733a2f2f516d53696e53595559526f3841437443583572636a526864413961476631564d734a413531514b677a326e57476449636f707972696768745054616e676f63727970746f2032303233466172746973744b54616e676f63727970746f496d656469615479706543706e674a636f6c6c656374696f6e5654616e676f63727970746f20436f6c6c656374696f6e4774776974746572582068747470733a2f2f747769747465722e636f6d2f74616e676f5f63727970746f0180ff. It was created like this:

```
...
const rawMetadata = Seed.buildPlutusData(token.metadata);
const plutusMetadata = PlutusData.from_json(JSON.stringify(rawMetadata), 1)
const fields = PlutusList.new();
fields.add(plutusMetadata);
fields.add(PlutusData.new_integer(BigInt.from_str(version.toString())));
fields.add(PlutusData.from_json(JSON.stringify(Seed.buildPlutusData(extra)), 1));
const plutusData = PlutusData.new_constr_plutus_data(
    ConstrPlutusData.new(toBigNum(0), fields)
)
plutusData.to_hex()
```

using CSL I put it in the invalid tx this way (also tried the commented line):

```
// const pData = PlutusData.new_constr_plutus_data(ConstrPlutusData.from_hex(inputData));
const pData = PlutusData.from_hex(inputData);
```

Tacking a closer look to the tx cbor structure I noticed the datum and redeemers are like this:

```
4: [
    121([
        {'name': 'TangoCIP0068#011', 'image': 'ipfs://QmSinSYUYRo8ACtCX5rcjRhdA9aGf1VMsJA51QKgz2nWGd', 'copyright': 'Tangocrypto 2023', 'artist': 'Tangocrypto', 'mediaType': 'png', 'collection': 'Tangocrypto Collection', 'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/tango_crypto'}, 
    1, 
    []
    ])
], 
5: [[1, 0, 122([[]]), [1943838, 544610828]], [0, 1, 121([[]]), [1943838, 544610828]]]
```

And from the error we have this:

```
he data is: Constr 0 [Map [(B \"name\",B \"TangoCIP0068#011\"),(B \"image\",B \"ipfs://QmSinSYUYRo8ACtCX5rcjRhdA9aGf1VMsJA51QKgz2nWGd\"),(B \"copyright\",B \"Tangocrypto 2023\"),(B \"artist\",B \"Tangocrypto\"),(B \"mediaType\",B \"png\"),(B \"collection\",B \"Tangocrypto Collection\"),(B \"twitter\",B \"https://twitter.com/tango_crypto\")],I 1,List []]
The redeemer is: Constr 0 [List []]
```

So no sure why cannot create the script context though.

Comment: The script context error can be a red herring. Double check for any reason why a script data may not be successfully deserialised.

Comment: Hi @james, I've no clue at this point what is happening, what should I look for? This is how my script is serialized: 
`referenceTokenValidateInstance :: Validator
referenceTokenValidateInstance = Validator $ fromCompiledCode ($$(compile [|| wrap ||]))
  where
    wrap label222 label100 policy = mkUntypedValidator $ referenceTokenValidate (unsafeFromBuiltinData label222) (unsafeFromBuiltinData label100) (unsafeFromBuiltinData policy)
` The minting script works and the only difference is `mkUntypedMintingPolicy` instead of `mkUntypedValidator`

Comment: I don't see how it could be expected to work if the only difference is the function being used because minting expects `(r -> sc -> Bool)` whereas spending requires `(d -> r -> sc -> Bool)`.  It's not apparent to me what the cause of your problem is. I can take a look if you are willing to give me full read access to the codebase.